# Desktop client for Google Tasks that sits in the tray area

Tags: desktop-client, google-apps

Is there a Windows desktop client for Google Tasks that sits in the system tray?

I'd like something which is not a web app, because I don't keep my browser open all the time and, besides, having to open a whole browser just for a small task list would strike me as a huge waste of resources.
I'd also like something that just sits there and which maybe can warn me about due dates, the next task due and such.

A small, single-purpose application would be best.

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a web app to manage my google tasks in a Trello like fashion.

I know it's not a native windows app but I can make an electron app out of it if you are interested.

it's called [TasksBoard.app](https://tasksboard.app), try it out and let me know what you think ;)

Cheers